# How to select particular range of values from joining two tables in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, sqlanywhere

I have two tables and I have to select the values from two tables based on the query

I have two tables like `tab1,tab2` and each having same columns `name,age,job,gender`. and in `tab 2` I have extra column `place`

I have to select all values from tab1 and tab2 where the gender is male

how to do it?

```
SELECT tab1.name,tab1.gender,tab1.age,tab2.place FROM tab1 INNER JOIN tab2 ON tab1.gender=mhdetail.gender where gender='male';
```

is this correct?

Comment: you are doing table join on which basis... i mean which column is same in both table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not looking for a join. You want an `Union`:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable1
WHERE Gender = 'Male'

UNION -- Or 'UNION ALL' if you want duplicates.

SELECT *
FROM MyTable2
WHERE Gender = 'Male'
```

A join would be used if you had 2 tables, and wanted info from the 2 tables, but only one table would contain the gender:

```
SELECT *
FROM   MyTable1
JOIN   MyTable2 ON MyTable1.ID = MyTable1.ID
WHERE  MyTable1.Gender = 'Male'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to be more specific on `JOIN` condition(s). If you don't have ids in both tables, but combination of name, gender, age is unique, then you can do it like this

```sql
SELECT t1.name,
       t1.gender,
       t1.age,
       t2.place 
  FROM tab1 t1 LEFT JOIN 
       tab2 t2 ON t1.gender = t2.gender AND
                  t1.name = t2.name AND
                  t1.age = t2.age    
 WHERE t1.gender='male';
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2839/1)**

Comment: With the name of his tables, I think that's actually what he wants. When he wrote that they have the same column, he probably meant "some of the same column", meaning the key.

Comment: But in this case, would it make a difference to just select all data from tab2 where gender is male?

Comment: It would make sense if data sets are different in both tables and(or) there more columns in real situation. If data sets are equal then I agree it makes no sense to use JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will results in many duplicate rows. Because it will become many to many relationship. If these two tables are related by any means like primary and foreign key relationship then join using these keys. Otherwise use union as posted in above answer.